# installation of wordpress with xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I want to install Wordpress on my pc so first, I need to install xampp.

After installation when I'm trying to start apache it is automatically shutting down. So I changed the localhost port number to 8080 then it started.

But now the problem is when I'm trying to run Wordpress it is not opening correctly.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlJJU.png) of my error. Please help with installation of Wordpress with the xampp

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check first if any other html file is working fine or not on the root directory inside (www) folder. If its working fine then try with http://localhost/wpfive
see my example screenshot for this.

Best of luck

[image]